# Display data from a query - I can't display it properly

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to show result from a query but I can't display it as it should.
I have two tables - `ordersheader` and `orderitems`.

`ordersheader` is the table for orders. It's structure is:
`idOrder`,`idCustomer`,`createdDate`,`orderDueDate`.

My table 'orderitems' contains separate orderitems for each order .It has the following structure:
`orderitem_id`,`idOrder`,`item_number`,`eggSize`,`quantity`,`price`.

These two tables are joined ON idOrder. One row from `ordersheader` corresponds to many rows in `orderitems` because one order could have many orderitems in it.
My problem is that I can't show them properly. It has to be shown like this:

http://prntscr.com/7lwnz7

and when you click Details it should look like that:

http://prntscr.com/7lwoan

Now,they are shown each orderitem on new line like this:

http://prntscr.com/7lworg
I have to make result from each idOrder to be displayed in one row.
Should I use inner loop and how to do that? 
My model is:

```html
<?php
function getOrders(){
    $date = new DateTime("now");
    $curr_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $this->db->select('ordersheader.*,customer.name,orderitems.*');
    $this->db->from('ordersheader'); 
    $this->db->join('orderitems', 'orderitems.idOrder = ordersheader.idOrder');
    $this->db->join('customer', 'customer.idCustomer = ordersheader.idCustomer');
    $this->db->where('DATE(orderDueDate)', $curr_date);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

My view is:

```html
<?php
 if($orderlist){
foreach($orderlist as $row) {
 ?> <tr class="overview">
                        <td><?php echo $row->idOrder; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><img src="<?= base_url();?>/assets/images/tick.png"></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->eggSize; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->quantity; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 60%;">
                                    60%
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>18:00</td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs view-full-order">Full</button></td>
                    </tr> <?php for($i=0;$i<count($row->eggSize); $i++) { ?>
                    <tr class="full hide">
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->eggSize; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->quantity; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: <?php echo $rand; ?>%;">
                                  <?php echo $rand; ?>%  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>14:00</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr><?php } ?>
 <?php } } ?>
             </tbody></table>
```

Comment: try your qyery with `$this->db->where('DATE(ordersheader.orderDueDate)', $curr_date);`

Comment: I've made it so: $this->db->where('DATE(orderDueDate)', $curr_date); This column orderDueDate is only in table `ordersheader`. Problem is that there are many orderitems for each order and I want to combine them in one row for each order.

Comment: use group by in your query

Comment: I tried this, but when I use group by, it shows only one orderitem from orderitems. I have to show them all for each order.

Comment: Now I added in my model: $this->db->group_by('orderitems.idOrder');  But how to display all eggSize for each order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
    function getOrders(){
        $date = new DateTime("now");
        $curr_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        $this->db->select('ordersheader.*,customer.name,GROUP_CONCAT(orderitems.item_number SEPARATOR ",") as item_number');
 $this->db->select('ordersheader.*,customer.name,GROUP_CONCAT(orderitems.priceSEPARATOR ",") as price');
 $this->db->select('ordersheader.*,customer.name,GROUP_CONCAT(orderitems.eggSize SEPARATOR ",") as eggSize');
        $this->db->from('ordersheader'); 
        $this->db->join('orderitems', 'orderitems.idOrder = ordersheader.idOrder');
        $this->db->join('customer', 'customer.idCustomer = ordersheader.idCustomer');
        $this->db->where('DATE(orderDueDate)', $curr_date);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! In model I added: $this->db->group_by('orderitems.idOrder');   But  when you click "Details" how to make these items to be in separate rows? And when you click "Details" for definite idOrder, it should be opened only separate orderitems for this idOrder. Should I use inner loop?